# How to connect a windows desktop (or any other desktop) remotely to a raspberry pi via different networks/wifis?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, ngrok

So, we are trying to build a commercial grade data collection system. We have to get very large and dense data from a raspberry pi device to any other device over all networks. All the stuff that I have tried so far has only worked when the two devices were connected to the same local network (VNC server, socket python, etc).

I have tried using ngrok, but it is not viable for us as it has restricted bandwidth for the free version. Ideally, we would like an ngrok alternative that is free, and does not have data restrictions and is safe. I have also tried using localtunnel, but could not install node.js on the raspberry pi device.

On socket we have tried to use this code on the client side of things:

```
import socket

msgFromClient = "This is your client."
bytesToSend = msgFromClient.encode('utf-8')
serverAddress = ('127.0.0.1', 2222)  # Replace with the actual public IP address of the server
bufferSize = 1024
UDPClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPClient.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddress)
data, address = UDPClient.recvfrom(bufferSize)
data = data.decode('utf-8')
print("Data from server:", data)
print("Server IP Address:", address[0])
print("Server port:", address)
```

On the server side:

```
import socket
    import time
    bufferSize = 1024
    msgFromServer = "howdy"
    serverIP = '127.0.0.1'
    bytesToSend = msgFromServer.encode('utf-8')
    RPIsocket = socket/socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    RPIsocket.bind((serverIP, serverPort))
    print("server is listening...")
    message, address = RPIsocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    message = message.decode('utf-8')
    print('message')
    print("Client address: ", address[0] #print the client address
    RPIsocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your case

Do you have an RPi from which you want to send data to other machines?

Or do you have a "cental" machine (server) and you want to send a file to the clients? From what you've explained  - your RPI device act like a server.

In the first case, if you want to send data from an RPi in one network to a RPI in another network - you can use SFTP/FTP or  HTTP + wget

in the case of the Server to client - there are configuration management tools for that. (f.e. ansible)

In our company, we are using qbee.io platform (https://qbee.io/).

For the case when you need to copy files from an RPI to RPI and you don't have direct access to them - we are using qbee-connect.

This is a desktop tool that builds VPN tunnel from machine to machine using a local (f.e. personal computer) as a man in the middle. The idea is that I can map a port in RPI1 and a port and RPI2 locally and do a copy.

For the case when we need to distribute a file (different files) to a different machine(s) - we are using their configuration engine. The beauty of it - is if the "original" file changes on the server (the one I distributed before, f.e. a new version of a package) configuration engine would detect that and re-send a new version to the devices that had a previous version. We are using this in our CI GitHub pipeline.

In both cases - network is not an issue because qbee establish a VPN connection.